# iOS UITextView with html contents, tap on image and zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I’m developing a Swift iOS application to display simple HTML content (text and images) inside a UITextView (with attributedString of course).
Text and images (plain img tags with remote images) are shown perfectly.
I’d like at this point, to let the user tap on the images and display them full screen and full size on a new view controller.

Any help would be appreciated.
I can intercept tap on images, following some old SO posts, but I can’t figure out how to “get” the image to pass to the new view controller.

Thanks.

Comment: If the image is from remote youll need to re-download it. Basically youll need to get the image url from the tap

Comment: That won’t be a problem. It’s the url itself I can’t find a way to get from the attributed string. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have used this open source in the past. https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel. Im not sure you’d like to introduce nor use it in your project but the solution on how to isolate a url should be in there (: hope it helps

Comment: I’ll give it a look tomorrow, first thing in the morning. Thanks for your help.